# determine the fundamental matrix $\psi$ satisfying $\psi(0) = I$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, determinant

In the following problem I am trying to determine the fundamental matrix $\psi$ satisfying $\psi(0) = I$ I am running into some problems toward the end. I was told not to use eulers formula $e^{it} = \cos t + i\sin t$ because the $i$'s will cancel out somewhere.

$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & -5 \\ 1 & -2\end{bmatrix}$$

Calculating the Eigenvalues,

$$det\begin{bmatrix}2-\lambda & -5 \\ 1 & -2-\lambda\end{bmatrix} $$
$$ (2-\lambda)(-2-\lambda) + 5 = 0$$
$$\lambda^2 = -1$$
$$\lambda = \pm i$$

**Case 1: $\lambda = i$**

$$\begin{bmatrix}2 - i & -5 \\ 1 & -2-i\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a  \\ b \end{bmatrix} = 0$$

$$a = (2+i)b$$
$$b = 1, a = 2+i$$
$$\lambda = i, x^{(1)} = \begin{bmatrix}2+i\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

**case 2: $\lambda = -i$**

$$\begin{bmatrix}2 + i & -5 \\ 1 & -2+i\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a  \\ b \end{bmatrix} = 0$$

$$a = (2-i)b$$
$$b = 1, a = 2-i$$
$$\lambda = i, x^{(1)} = \begin{bmatrix}2-i\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Hence,

$$\psi (t) = \begin{bmatrix}(2+i)e^{it} & (2-i)e^{-it} \\ e^{it} & e^{-it}\end{bmatrix}$$

Then the fundamental matrix can be calculated by,

$$F(t) = \psi (t) \psi ^{-1} (0)$$

$$\psi ^{-1}(0) = \begin{bmatrix}(2+i) & (2-i) \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} ^{-1} = \frac{1}{2i} \begin{bmatrix}(1) & (-2+i) \\ -1 & 2+i\end{bmatrix} $$

Hence,

$$F (t) = \begin{bmatrix}(2+i)e^{it} & (2-i)e^{-it} \\ e^{it} & e^{-it}\end{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2i} \begin{bmatrix}(1) & (-2+i) \\ -1 & 2+i\end{bmatrix}$$

The correct answer is the following so clearly I have went wrong somewhere but I am not sure where and am looking for some help, thanks!

$$\psi(t) = \begin{bmatrix}\cos t+2\sin t & -5\sin t \\ \sin t & \cos t-2\sin t\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Have you tried simplifying $F(t)$? I only checked it very quickly, but it seems correct to me.

Comment: I am not sure how to simplify since it's multiple by 1/2i

Comment: Just use the fact that $\sin(t) = \frac{e^{it} -e^{-it}}{2i}$ and $\cos(t) = \frac{e^{it} +e^{-it}}{2}$.

Comment: Okay I was unaware of those

Comment: So how can I combine those to get the fiball solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$
F(t) = \begin{bmatrix}(2+i)e^{it} & (2-i)e^{-it} \\ e^{it} & e^{-it}\end{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2i} \begin{bmatrix}(1) & (-2+i) \\ -1 & 2+i\end{bmatrix}= \frac{1}{2i}\begin{bmatrix}(2+i)e^{it}-(2-i)e^{-it} & (2+i)(-2+i)e^{it}+(2+i)(2-i)e^{-it} \\ e^{it}-e^{-it} & (-2+i)e^{it}
 + (2+i)e^{-it}\end{bmatrix} \\
=\begin{bmatrix}2\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i} +\frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2} & \frac{-5e^{it} +5e^{-it}}{2i}  \\ \frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i} & \frac{-2e^{it}+2e^{-it}{2i}}{2i}+ \frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}\end{bmatrix} \\
=\begin{bmatrix}2\sin(t) +\cos(t) & -5\sin(t) \\ \sin(t) & -2\sin(t)+ \cos(t)\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So your solution is correct.

Comment: In the matrix in position 1 1 why does the - Come out of the e^-it

Comment: @jh123 That's just an error, it should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!